# How to delete a database whose owner is not cloudsqlsuperuser via Cloud SQL Admin API?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

We have a system which programmatically creates and deletes databases in an [Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/postgresql?hl=en) instance. These databases are owned by an user different from `cloudsqlsuperuser`.

We try to delete them with the [`databases.delete`](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/admin-api/rest/v1/databases/delete) API call, via the [`@googleapis/sqladmin` NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googleapis/sqladmin). When we call it, though, we get this error:

```
Invalid request: failed to delete database "DBNAmE".
Detail: pq: must be owner of database lportal.
(Please use psql client to delete database that is not owned by "cloudsqlsuperuser").
```

While we could try to use `psql` to do the deletion, or maybe use a PostgreSQL Node client to run `DROP DATABASE`, I wonder:

Is there a way to delete a database whose owner is not `cloudsqlsuperuser` via Cloud SQL Admin API?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to delete a database whose owner is not cloudsqlsuperuser via Cloud SQL Admin API?

That error message gives me the impression that there is not. Given that it's already pointing out to use the `psql` client instead.

That said, I would like to point out that the [`@google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector) is a handy package from the Google Cloud SDK team built on top of `@googleapis/sqladmin` that makes it extra simple and secure to connect to a Cloud SQL instance.

I would strongly advise you to give it a try in case you decide to use a node client to run `DROP DATABASE`, there are [quickstarters](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector#using-with-postgresql), [samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector/tree/71b56846bb97195ee555c823c3cb1c847ac552e6/examples) and [tests](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector/blob/71b56846bb97195ee555c823c3cb1c847ac552e6/system-test/pg-connect.cjs) that you can potentially start from.